# custom httphandler throwing exception while doing rewrite path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want redirect to a file which is at the root level of the application , but i am getting the following error.

I did the following things to achieve the same

1. I have a virtual directory under root which is sample
2. Added handler with some  custom name like  .zpy which resolves to .net
   root/sample(sample is a virtual directory)
3. Added the mapping in the web.config

   ```
   <add verb="*" path="*.zpy" type="MyUrlHttpHandler, WebProj"/>
   ```
4. And this is the code

   ```
   string finalUrl= "http://www.test.com/test.asp";
   context.RewritePath(finalUrl);
   IHttpHandler hnd = PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(finalUrl, null, context);
   hnd.ProcessRequest(context);
   ```

I get the following error

**http://www.test.com/test.asp is not a valid virtual path.**

The code is getting executed but i am unable to send the request to test.asp which is at
root level.

i tried moving the handler to root  and having handler at the root level , but its still throwing the same error

exception stack trace

```
HttpException (0x80004005): 'http://locwww.test.com/test.asp' is not a valid virtual path.]
   System.Web.VirtualPath.Create(String virtualPath, VirtualPathOptions options) +8855691
   System.Web.HttpContext.RewritePath(String path, Boolean rebaseClientPath) +116
   System.Web.HttpContext.RewritePath(String path) +6
   ADC.Web.Code.ApcUrlHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in C:\Projects\webproj\urlHttpHandler.cs:30
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Comment: 1. It throws an exception, not an error. 2. Please post the complete exception, including all the inner exceptions and stack traces.

Comment: @John , i am getting the above error , its saying its a valid virtual path

Comment: @john can you help me with this, as it is kind of a urgent delivarable for me..

Comment: @gov: you probably should have learned the fundamentals of .NET before the requirement became urgent. If you don't know what an exception is, then it's kind of too late.

Comment: @john , let me post the error

Comment: @gov: see my answer below. And, please don't ever use the word "error" when you mean "exception". It suggests that you don't know .NET.

Comment: @thanks for the suggestion , sure in hurry i posted that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing makes no sense. Is the "http://www.test.com/test.asp" file an asp.net file? If not, then it won't be possible to get a compiled page instance!

Try using Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer instead.

Comment: @john thanks very much , i posted the error also , test.asp is a legacy page we have , which needs to be executed from root folder..

Comment: @john let me explain you my requirement in more clear , there is a isapi rule which resolves to some dubby page .zpy which calls the httphandler , there i want to redirect to a traditional asp based on some logic ,may i know is it possible

Comment: @gov: you can't execute it that way. You need Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer or something else.

Comment: @john , we want to avoid Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer...that is the reason taking this httphandler approach

Comment: @gov: if you wanted to avoid them, then you should have trashed the .asp file before you got to this point. Sorry, what you're doing just fundamentally won't work. An ASP page is not a handler - it's not even .NET code.

Comment: @gov: is the ASP page even within the same web site?

Comment: @john thanks very much for your detailed explanation and time , let me do some more research on this.. my requirement is based on some logic in .net , i have to redirect to traditionaly asp or a .net page. i will ready more about this and get back to you , but thanks very much.

Comment: @gov: also, you may have some options depending on which IIS version you're using.

Comment: @gov: yeah, this keeps getting better and better. :-( You may want to remind your management how much money Microsoft (or anyone else) spends to enhance old products.

Comment: @gov: and before you think I'm ragging on you, "me too".

Comment: @john , do you have any other suggestions for me...??

Comment: @gov: first, make sure Management actually _reads_ this discussion, and second, keep trying to make something work. They may finally learn how much more time they waste by maintaining legacy code than they would spend if they upgraded it.

Comment: @John last thing , if you have time can you explain me few lines why we cannot execute asp file? based on that i will do some research and speak to management.

Comment: @gov: `PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(finalUrl, null, context)` compiles an **ASP.NET** page into a .NET object that implements `IHttpHandler`. Your ASP page is not an ASP.NET page, so cannot  be compiled by ASP.NET.

Comment: @john , excellent explaination , i got it now. Thanks once again.

Comment: @john one last question , if i execute any .htm or .aspx from root , it should work right..

Comment: john , when i try to execute .html file , it throws below error There is no build provider registered for the extension '.html'. You can register one in the <compilation><buildProviders> section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.

Comment: @gov: good research. Note that if your .asp file was a .aspx file, it would work.

Comment: @john , you are right , if i have .html or .htm its working after adding .asp , .html entry's in web.config , whatever you said is right.

Answer (score 2):

Given your discussion elsewhere, if you'd actually be happy with a *redirect*, then that's simple:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.test.com/test.asp", true);
```

That's going to be a lot simpler than trying to serve the original content from this request.

Comment: as it does 301 redirect , is there any otherway other than reponse.redirect , thanks for your answer

Comment: @gov: You specifically said in one of your comments: "i have to redirect" - are you saying you *don't* want to redirect? You're really not being clear on this.

Comment: thanks for your answer, as redirect can have some performance issues , my team is looking for options to use httphandler to rewrite that path...instead of response.redirect or server.transfer

Answer (score 2):

if you're trying to redirect to a page/handler in the root folder then simple using this path: ~/mypage.aspx.

And rather than use ReWritePath and everything else you're doing in your handler just use

```
Response.Redirect("~/test.asp");
```

This has the advantage is working in your dev environment as well as in production because you're not hard coding the complete url. ASP.NET will resolve the "~/" to be the root of your application even if the application is in a subfolder.